# PyDev package explorer

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I just added PyDev to My Eclipse Juno with Java. Unfortunately, when I use Python with Eclipse , I am unable to change the directory of the package explorer. If someone could give me instructions on how to do so I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to 'change' the PyDev package explorer dir... In Eclipse things are centered around 'projects', so, what you need to do is link/create projects and they should appear in the PyDev package explorer. See: http://pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-HowdoIimportexistingprojects%2FsourcesintoPyDev%3F for details for importing existing projects.